# New Document opening Home Page in Document Library

Tags: 2013, document-library, new-document

The Environment is SharePoint 2013.
When I click on **New Document** in Document Library, it gives me options to choose if I want a word document or excel and so on.
When I click on Word or any other options, it opens Home Page.

Can anyone help me to find out why this is happening

Comment: Do you have office installed?

Comment: if you mean office desktop, yes it is installed